# Can I inner join a previous SQL query then perform counts

Tags: sql-server, join, count

I've created a query from a fairly large database.
At the moment each single procedure undertaken by an employee appears as 3 identical timed rows Each row informs the site where procedure occurred, equipment part used and whether day or night.
I want to combine the rows with matching name and time together to create a single row containing all the other fields.
I then want to be able to create a log for the employee to show how many of each procedure has been undertaken and the site and technique used.

I figure an inner join may be the best way to do this but would be grateful for further help as to how to set this up on a sub-query.

Current query:

```
SELECT procedure, employee, chart_time, form,  
FROM cust.records 
WHERE employeeID IN () AND procedurelabel LIKE 'rad1'
```

Really appreciate the help

Comment: Not clear at all what you are trying to do.   I recommend reading this and trying your question again:  https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Please add DDL, DML Scripts with sample inputs and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Your question could use a little clarification... not least being the DDL for your table and a few notes on what each column is.  Nonetheless, assuming these rows are all in the `cust.records` table and that each set of 3 rows have a unique combination of name and time, you could do something like this...

```
SELECT -- first select fields common to all rows... may as well take these from the first table
       records1.procedure, records1.employee, records1.chart_time, 
       -- ... then select records from your joins
       records2.some_column,  
       records3.some_column
  FROM cust.records records1 
 INNER JOIN WHERE cust.records records2 on records1.chart_time = records2.chart_time
                                       and records1.procedure = record2.procedure
                                       and records1.employee = records2.employee
                                       -- Possible condition required here to not join this row to itself
                                       -- or to explicitly join to a specific type of row
 INNER JOIN WHERE cust.records records3 on records1.chart_time = records3.chart_time
                                       and records1.procedure = record3.procedure
                                       and records1.employee = records3.employee
                                       -- Possible condition required here to not join this row to itself
                                       -- or to explicitly join to a specific type of row

 WHERE employeeID IN () 
   AND procedurelabel LIKE 'rad1'
   -- Possible condition required here specify the row to select for records1.
```

Might also be worth considering a table re-design since what you've described doesn't sound normalised.